# How do I turn off the update notifications on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: updates, 22.04, notification

How do I turn off the update notifications on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS? By that I mean, those pop up notifications that appear suddenly on the screen.

I want to change that, because I don't see any use for these, since most of the updates are done automatically (deb and snaps). And for those that require manual intervention to update (flatpaks), I do usually run the appropriate command on the terminal once a week.

Thanks.

Comment: Try launching "Software & Updates", navigate to `Updates` tab, and disable `Automatically check for Updates` by setting to Never.

Comment: @MerilynNe thank you for taking your time to respond to my post. Sorry for replying so late, but I got sick for a few days, so I am just checking this thread. Anyway, I dont want to disable that, since I like the auto-update option. It is just that I dont want the pop up. But that is it.

Answer (score 0):

on Plasma System Settings, Personalization, Other notifications, upgrade information, and gone!

Plasma notifications, upgrade info uncheck:

[image: Plasma notificaciones, upgrade info uncheck]

Comment: Does that mute "updates" popups, or just "upgrades", like to the latest version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

and for a more detailed configuration go to *Plasma System Settings*: under *Personalization*, choose *Notifications*, then click Applications *Configure* buttom and under *System Services/Plasma Workspace* click on **Configure Events**.
Its really full of options for notifications setup (sounds,message popups, entries for the taskbar, actions...)

[Plasma workspace -> Configure Notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFJ6U.png)